# Get latest rows by date from aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hey i'm kinda stuck with this query. Using SQL-server

i have in the table, UNIQUE(date, medId, userId)

I have this table

```
date       | medId | userId | Quantity
2016-06-10 |   2   |   1    |   28
2016-06-07 |   1   |   1    |   19
2016-06-06 |   1   |   1    |   10
```

i want to get the row with the max date, per group of medId,userId, in this case
i would get

```
2016-06-10 |   2   |   1    |   28
2016-06-07 |   1   |   1    |   19
```

thanks in advance!

i've tried this

```
SELECT 
  a.userMedStockDate,
  a.userMedStockMedId, 
  a.userMedStockUserId,
  a.userMedStockQuantity
FROM (SELECT  
        MAX(userMedStockDate) AS userMedStockDate,
        userMedStockQuantity,
        userMedStockUserId,
        userMedStockMedId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by userMedStockMedId,userMedStockUserId 
                           ORDER BY MAX(userMedStockDate) desc) AS rnk
      FROM UserMedStock
      GROUP BY
        userMedStockUserId, 
        userMedStockQuantity,
        userMedStockMedId) a
WHERE a.rnk = 1
```

[SOLVED]

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
 select * from 
(
select 
[date] , medId, userId ,Quantity
,row_number() over (partition by medId, userId order by [date] desc) as rowid 
from yourtable
) as x
where rowid = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Could also try this:

```
select y.* from 
table1 y inner join 
(
SELECT [Date] = MAX([Date]), medId, userId
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY medId, userId
) x on y.[Date] = x.[Date] and y.medId = x.medId and y.userId = x.userId
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed the fields to my actual table but here

```
SELECT 
a.userMedStockDate, a.userMedStockMedId, a.userMedStockUserId,      a.userMedStockQuantity
FROM(
SELECT  
MAX(userMedStockDate) AS userMedStockDate,
userMedStockQuantity,
userMedStockUserId,
userMedStockMedId,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(partition by userMedStockMedId, userMedStockUserId ORDER BY MAX(userMedStockDate) desc) AS rnk
FROM UserMedStock
GROUP BY userMedStockUserId, userMedStockQuantity, userMedStockMedId
) a
WHERE a.rnk = 1
```